# python label not changing dynamically

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to see continuously changing value of label in tkinter window. But I'm not seeing any of it unless I make a keyboard interrupt in MS-CMD while running which shows me the latest assigned value to label. Plz tell me ..What's going on & what's the correct code ??

```
import random
from Tkinter import *

def server() :
 while True:
  x= random.random()
  print x   
  asensor.set(x)



app=Tk()
app.title("Server")
app.geometry('400x300+200+100')

b1=Button(app,text="Start Server",width=12,height=2,command=server)
b1.pack()

asensor=StringVar()

l=Label(app,textvariable=asensor,height=3)
l.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `server` is called when you click the button, but that function contains an infinite loop. It just keep generating random numbers and sending these to `asensor`. You are probably not seeing any of it because the `server` function is run in the same thread as the GUI and it never gives the label a chance to update.

If you remove the `while True` bit from your code, a new number will be generate each time you click the button. Is that what you wanted to do?

---

Edit after comment by OP:

I see. In that case your code should be changed as follows:

```
import random
from Tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, StringVar


def server():
    x = random.random()
    print x
    asensor.set(x)


def slowmotion():
    server()
    app.after(500, slowmotion)


app = Tk()
app.title("Server")
app.geometry('400x300+200+100')
b1 = Button(app, text="Start Server", width=12, height=2, command=slowmotion)
b1.pack()
asensor = StringVar()
asensor.set('initial value')
l = Label(app, textvariable=asensor, height=3)
l.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

I also introduced a new function, `slowmotion`, which does two things: 1) calls `server`, which updates displays the value, and 2) schedules itself to be executed again in 500ms. `slowmotion` is first ran when you first click the button.

The problem with your code was that it runs an infinite loop in the main GUI thread. This means once `server` is running, the GUI will not stop and will not get a chance to display the text you asked it to display.

Comment: No.. I do need to run it inside while loop. I want to see changing value in tkinter window. Is it possible with some modification ??